# How do I force https redirect on static files in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a ASP.NET Core app that has HTTPS redirection enabled. The problem is that HTTPS redirection doesn´t work on static files, so the front-end is in a different port than the back-end when I enter the site with http and this causes CORS to block all requests made to the back-end. I tried allowing CORS to all requests (for testing, of course) but no matter what I did, the requests failed. Only visiting the front end with https worked.How do I force https redirect on static files with ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Is `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` before `app.UseStaticFiles()` in Startup?

Comment: `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` is after `app.UseFileServer()` in Startup.

Comment: @Alejandro it has to come before, not after. You can read further here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/

Comment: It still does not redirect static files to https.

Comment: What has happened that makes you think that, "HTTPS redirection doesn´t work on static files?" I ask because, if I run a `dotnet new mvc` site, navigating to `http://localhost:5000/css/site.css` does redirect to `https://localhost:5001/css/site.css`. What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: I didn´t use `dotnet new mvc`. I used `dotnet new webapi` since the site was intended to be just an api first, then I used `vue-cli` to create the front-end and configured it to be built in wwwroot. If I type `http://localhost:5000` then I don´t get redirected to `https://localhost:5001`. The css get redirected fine though.

Answer (score 4):

Based on my expeirence, you must add this code to the startup.cs file

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.HttpsPort = 443;
            });
```

You have to love Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#require-https). 6 paragraphs below the incomplete example they tell you about this requirement:

> If no port is set:
>
> - Requests aren't redirected.

You can set port using the following techniques:

The port can be configured by setting the:

- ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT environment variable.
- http_port host configuration key (for example, via hostsettings.json or a command
- line argument).

  - HttpsRedirectionOptions.HttpsPort. See the preceding

Comment: Adding that code didn't work at all. I even tried using URL rewriter but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
    {
        var request = context.Context.Request;
        var response = context.Context.Response;
        UrlRewriteUtils.RedirectIfHttp(request, response);
    }
});
```

And here is the Utility method.

```
public class UrlRewriteUtils 
{
       public static void RedirectIfHttp(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
       {
            string reqProtocol;
            if (request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-Proto"))
                reqProtocol = request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"][0];
            else if (request.IsLocal())
                reqProtocol = "https";
            else
                reqProtocol = request.IsHttps ? "https" : "http";

            if (reqProtocol.ToLower() != "https")
            {
                var newUrl = new StringBuilder()
                    .Append("https://").Append(request.Host)
                    .Append(request.PathBase).Append(request.Path)
                    .Append(request.QueryString);
                response.Redirect(newUrl.ToString(), true);
            }
        }
    }
```